# Поиск одинаковых, но с разными ссылками объектов

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется массив структуры `[[N, N], [N, N]...]`, и мне надо найти в этом массиве значение [A, B]. Вроде всё просто, можно использовать arr.indexOf(), однако он сверяет объекты по ссылкам, а не по их значению.

Да, я мог бы реализовать это в лоб простым перебором, однако мне интересны "изящные" решения (в одну-две строки) если такие имеются. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "однако он сверяет объекты по ссылкам, а не по их значению"  --- ш-ш-ш-шта??

Comment: `JSON.stringify([1, 4]) === JSON.stringify([1, 4]); //  true` --- может это нужно?

Comment: Может используя `flat`? (`Array.prototype.flat()`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: что значит _найти_? Проверить наличие элемента или узнать index?

Comment: Суть в том, что если попробовать [[1, 2],[3, 4]].indexOf([3, 4]) то он вернёт -1, потому что мы сверяем два разных объекта

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, _**что значит найти?** Проверить наличие элемента или узнать index?_

Comment: Значит узнать его индекс

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, тогда смотри ссылку от Alexey Ten. В этот метод можно передать функцию, в которой будет проверяться соответствие элемента условию. Можно написать любую проверку.